# Number of comment flags always equals number of upvotes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, comment-flags

Since the reskin of the [10k flagged post/comment review page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), I've noticed a curious trend:

[image: hot freehand mspaint circle action, yo]

Each of those flagged comments has the same number of upvotes as flags.  At first I thought it was just some curious happenstance, but the numbers *never* seem to vary, and it's been happening for days.  Comments with no upvotes also happen to have no flags.  Ever.

Flags that I add don't show up.  Upvotes that I add also increment the flag count.

Comment: (fixed next deploy)

Comment: @Marc I can't flag you. :(

Comment: @muntoo - I don't understand; is that a bug report?

Comment: @Marc If someone thinks a comment is 'funny' they may upvote the comment. Then, they may realize the comment to be out of context/inappropriate/etc, and decide to flag it. Oh wait... they can't flag it anymore!

Comment: @muntoo an edge case. And IMO "by design" - they've already said it was *good*. There is always mod flag...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, that probably just means that in the cut-down 10k view I am showing the wrong counter; my bad. Diamond moderators get an expanded view there that shows the counts *per reason*, which is why I didn't spot it. It should be trivial to fix. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: I'm spamming my related bug report - [Number of Comment Flags isn't Displayed for Unvoted Comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93083)